# f is continuous on $(X,\tau)$ iff pre-image of set’s interior is subset of pre-interior of set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

$f: (X,\tau_1) \to (Y,\tau_2)$
Show $f$ is continuous on $(X,\tau_1) $ if and only if $\forall B \subseteq Y$ , ${f^-1}(interior(B)) \subseteq interior(f^{-1}(B))$

I don’t have any problem in first implication (let f is continuous in X then pre-image of interior of B is a subset of interior of pre-image of B) but I am not sure about converse. Which open set should I use? I have tried $interior(B)$ but it seems like wrong to me. Could someone show this implication clearly for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof by contrapositive.**

If $f$ is not continuous, there exists some open set $B \in \tau_2$ such that $f^{-1}(B) \notin \tau_1$, i.e. its preimage is not open.

Then, $\text{int}(f^{-1}(B)) \subsetneq f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(\text{int}(B))$, so $f^{-1}(\text{int}(B)) \not\subseteq \text{int}(f^{-1}(B))$.

---

**Direct proof.**

Let $B \in \tau_2$ be open. Then $f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(\text{int}(B)) \subseteq \text{int}(f^{-1}(B))$ by assumption. Since $f^{-1}(B)$ is contained in its own interior, it must be open.

Comment: If we think directly without contradiction?

Comment: I ve done this direct proof via same way but I could not be sure on this case: theorem should be valid for all subsets of Y not only opens subsets. Is it true that supposing B is open?

Comment: @esrabasar In that direction, the *assumption* holds for any subset $B$ of $Y$. In order to prove that $f$ is continuous, it is fine to consider only certain kinds of $B$ (namely open sets); you don't have to use all the assumptions. However, in the other direction, when you need to prove that the condition holds for all subsets $B$, you do need to handle all the cases of $B$.

Comment: Aww I have just realized my mistake. I have said B is open in other direction but I have not used since it is not necessary. Thank you so much